# Run a event when check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an application where, ehen i will click on a checkbox, to disable it. So, if i will click on first checkbox, to disable the first and so on. For  this i made:

```js
function onChange(checkedValues) {
  console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
}
const disabled = false;

const check = e => {
  console.log(e.target.disabled);
  let a = e.target.disabled;
  return disabled === true;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} onChange={onChange}>
    <Row>
      <Col span={8}>
        <Checkbox disabled={disabled} onChange={check} value="A">
          A
        </Checkbox>
      </Col>
      <Col span={8}>
        <Checkbox value="B">B</Checkbox>
      </Col>
      <Col span={8}>
        <Checkbox value="C">C</Checkbox>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Checkbox.Group>,
  document.getElementById("container")
```

But it does not work. How to fix the code?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-ant-design-demo-87ycs?file=/index.js:156-822

Answer (score 1):

Use e.currentTarget as working in this vanilla-js example (Your check-function is basically the same as in vanilla):

```js
function check(e){
  e.currentTarget.disabled = true;
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('change',check);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="a" />A <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="b" />B <br />
<input type="checkbox" value="c" />C <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an Array to map and store the disabled status would be fine.

---

```
const list = ["A", "B", "C"];

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(
    new Array(list.length).fill(false)
  );
  const check = idx => e => {
    const temp = [...disabled];
    temp[idx] = true;
    setDisabled(temp);
  };
  return (
    <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} onChange={onChange}>
      <Row>
        {list.map((x, idx) => (
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox
              key={idx}
              disabled={disabled[idx]}
              onChange={check(idx)}
              value={x}
            >
              {x}
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </Checkbox.Group>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

---

Demo:

[image]

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button   , it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would work: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-with-grid-ant-design-demo-ucpgr

So to summarise:

- Custom component to check if the current checkbox is checked, if so, then disable it
- Store the state in a context, so we don't have to pass it via the props every time